# Recommended Books to Study Numerical Linear Algebra

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I am currently struggling as an undergraduate to cope with my Numerical Linear Algebra course due to the fact that my professor refers to her lecture notes that lack clear explanation to theorems and application. I hope someone can recommend me a useful book about Numerical Linear Algebra that includes the following topics :

1. BLAS Operations and Implementations.
2. Basic Concepts for Matrix Computations : Norms, Square Matrices, Gram Schmidt Procedure, Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors, Schur's Decomposition, Singular Values...
3. Gaussian Elimination and PLU Decomposition.
4. Least Squares Problems and QR Factorizations.

Note that there is a user who asked a similar question however that user wanted a book that focuses on MATLAB implementations as for me I am searching for a book that gives me a fundamental understanding of Numerical Linear Algebra as I am an udergraduate.

Comment: Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen is a good book.

Comment: Not especialy oriented towards numerical linear algebra: "Numerical Recipes" by Press, Teukolsky, Vetterling is rich and has a very entertaining style important for self study... different editions (in Pascal, in Fortran, in C...). Some numerical analysts don't like it precisely precisely because its "recipe" style, but don't care... A book that doesn't look in your scope but has a nice style: 'Numerical Methods in finance and Economics' by Brandimarte.

Comment: The different books by G. Strang.

Comment: Matrix Computations by Golub & Van Loan has all you need.